# Shared data in ASP.NET MVC Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What's the best way to provide shared data to my views?

For example, I want to be able to just put <%= Model.Title %> in my master page, or something similar.

In that scenario, is it better to override the ViewPage classes I need? Or just use a shared model object?

I'm currently trying to do the shared model object approach -- it works; just a lot of code and view pages to edit...

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976493/asp-net-mvc-set-viewdata-for-masterpage-in-base-controller would be interesting to you

Comment: Thanks eu-ge-ne, that's a more sensible solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put ContentPlaceHolder on your MasterPage and in views place shared data into it