# How to pass a variable from Controller Initialization to a Master Page in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

in a controller:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    if (db == null) { db = new myRepository(); }
    if (currentCalendar == null)
    {
        currentCalendar = 
             db.FindCalendarInfoByUrl(
                  requestContext.RouteData.Values["calurl"].ToString());

        // if not found ... show Unavailable Content View
        if (currentCalendar == null)
            RedirectToAction("ContentNotAvailable");

        // to show in the MasterPage
        Session["GoogleId"] = currentCalendar.GoogleAnalyticsId; 
    }

    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

`Session` variable is not yet defined in this time of the request, and I can't use `ViewData` either as It's always null...

How can I use to pass this 2 variables `GoogleId` and `CalendarUrl` to the `MasterPage`?

I'm thinking that I could use `Cache`, but there are so many and I'm not yet into Caching:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-11-17_2328.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-11-17_2328.png)

**What is my best option** to accomplish this?

Comment: ViewData should not be null in the `Initialize`. Please check again and show the error that pops up.

Comment: `ViewData` is `null` in the `MasterPage`, `Session` is invalid in the Ìnitialization`method. :(

Comment: dang... `ViewData` is there.. I was just missing the correct controller (need sleep, urgently!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your ViewData is null in the Master Page, but try overriding the `OnActionExecuting` event.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

Also take a look at the following:

1. [ASP.NET MVC - Set ViewData for masterpage in base controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976493/asp-net-mvc-set-viewdata-for-masterpage-in-base-controller)
2. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs